# Merge sublists of nested list if first index element match

Tags: python, data-structures

`list = [['100', '88', '', ''], ['100', '', '68', ''], ['100', '', '', '58'],['102', '28', '', ''], ['102', '', '2', ''], ['104', '11', '', ''], ['104', '', '2', ''], ['110', '2', '', ''], ['202', '', '14', ''], ['202', '37429', '', '']]`

need to merge the sub list on first index value.

`output = [['100', 88, '68', '58'], ['102', 28, '2', ''],['104', 11, '2', ''],['110', 2, '', ''],['202', '37429', 14, '']]`

Comment: If any answer helps close the question by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of list use any other name.

Use `itertools's groupby` and groupby 1st element then merge them together but that will give you list of list so you need to flatten them by using `itertools chain`.

Note: I have also removed empty strings. You can try either to modify the code as per your need for that empty string or you can append them later making each list size as 4.

```
from itertools import groupby
import itertools
li = [['100', '88', '', ''], ['100', '', '68', ''], ['100', '', '', '58'],['102', '28', '', ''], ['102', '', '2', ''], ['104', '11', '', ''], ['104', '', '2', ''], ['110', '2', '', ''], ['202', '', '14', ''], ['202', '37429', '', '']]
tuple_list = list(map(tuple,li))
output_list = [[idx]+list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list(filter(None, i[1:])) for i in e)) for idx, e in groupby(tuple_list, lambda x: x[0])]
```

---

**output_list:**

```
[['100', '88', '68', '58'],
 ['102', '28', '2'],
 ['104', '11', '2'],
 ['110', '2'],
 ['202', '14', '37429']]
```

If you want empty string also:

```
output_list = [([idx]+list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list(filter(None, i[1:])) for i in e))+['']*4)[:4] for idx, e in groupby(tuple_list, lambda x: x[0])]
```

---

```
[['100', '88', '68', '58'],
 ['102', '28', '2', ''],
 ['104', '11', '2', ''],
 ['110', '2', '', ''],
 ['202', '14', '37429', '']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The more basic way is to make two nested loops, write a condition if the first index match, move them to a new list.
You can try to convert them to numpy array which will make them a 2d array then you can compare easier